# Wordpress doesn't display PAGES link on Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

I have had this site since 2014 and have been updating regularly. All of a sudden, there is no link on the dashboard to access existing pages. They are there (viewable), but there appears to be no way to edit existing pages or to add new pages. Where did the expected link go, and how do I get it back?

Comment: Usually, if you are logged in and are *viewing*  a page, there's an "edit page" link in the black top (admin) bar - did that disappear too? (that would be at least a way to access page edit mode)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest re-uploading all the Wordpress core files. I suspect some file is missing or corrupt.

Make sure that all of your file permissions are correct (FTP/SSH).

It is a good idea to disable plugins one by one and switch to a default theme as well and see if the `Pages` menu item appears in your Wordpress administration. You can find the culprit this way.

**PS. Backup the site prior to re-uploading the files.**

Comment: How do I re-load the Wordpress core files? Also, why would my file permissions have changed without my knnowing it?

Comment: If your Wordpress install or server has been compromised, malicious files can change other files permissions. You can download the latest (or same) Wordpress version you have and re-upload all files, but the ones related to your theme/custom plugins. Also keep a backup of your wp-config.php fie.